# Addition and subtraction not working with Armadillo sparse matrices

Tags: c++, armadillo

I don't understand why `+` and `-` operations are not working on Armadillo sparse matrices while `*` and `/` are working correctly.  (As per doc, `+` and `-` should work as well [link](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<armadillo>  

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    sp_mat A(5,6);
    A(0,0) = 1;
    A(1,0) = 2;
    cout << 2 + A << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

see the error below.

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
             from demo.cpp:1:
   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:327:5: note:            template<class _Iterator> typename std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type std::operator-(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator-(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator.h:327:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
demo.cpp:28:9: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’ and ‘int’
 cout<<2-A<<endl;
```

Comment: Assigning a value to a temporary seems pretty redundant to me. But maybe you can clear me up.

Comment: In  the documentation provided, the operator+ is only used with 2 sparse matrices. Adding 2 to a matrix doesnt make sense ....

Comment: @cad. Then why `cout<<2*A` works?

Comment: @Ben. adding 2 make sense for dense matrices. it's called element-wise addition. element-wise multiplication is working for sparse matrices but not addition.

Comment: Element-wise addition is an uncommon operation for most matrix math that's actually useful, unlike 'element-wise multiplication' (which is much better thought of as multiplication of a matrix by a scalar -- a well-defined operation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a scalar to a matrix is equivalent to adding the scalar to every element in the matrix.  In a *sparse* matrix, most of the elements are zero, and are not explicitly stored, which significantly reduces memory usage.

So, adding a scalar to a *sparse* matrix is ill advised, as in effect it would turn a *sparse* matrix into a *dense* matrix, which **defeats the purpose** of having a sparse matrix in the first place (reducing memory use).

Given the above observation, it looks like Armadillo developers prevented this problem from happening by simply not defining the addition of scalars to *sparse* matrices. Adding scalars to *dense* matrices works [perfectly fine](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#operators).

Answer (score 1):

It's simply not supported (yet?). There's still hope since the doc says that
*support for sparse matrices in this version is preliminary*.

In the mean time, you can make use of the in-place addition and substraction, through a submatrix view, e.g.,

```
using namespace arma;
Mat<double> m(5, 6, fill::ones);
SpMat<double> spm(m);
spm(span::all, span::all) += 2;
```

Comment: I liked this answer better than my own, so I deleted mine.

Answer (score 0):

It says right on the documents for their API what '+' and '-' are set to do. I think you should read the documentation, figure out what is you are trying to do, and ask that question instead.

http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat

> operators:  +  -  *  /  %  ==  !=  <=  >=  <  >
>   Overloaded operators for mat, vec, rowvec and cube classes
>
> Meanings:
>
> '+'    Addition of two objects
>   '-'    Subtraction of one object from another or negation of an object
>   '/'    Element-wise division of an object by another object or a scalar
>   '*'    Matrix multiplication of two objects; not applicable to the cube class unless multiplying a cube by a scalar

Based on your error it's pretty obvious that they didn't define the operator for a `sp_mat` and a scalar, they defined it for a `sp_mat` and an `sp_mat`.

I'm not pretending to be a master of this topic; I just read the API.  You should probably take a look at the headers.